# How do i merge multiple rows data in one row in t-sql but string and numeric both

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Data is following :

```
Code  Article   Amount  Paid   Balance  
8001  Black     8000    7000    1000
```

I want to see it like this:

```
8001 (Black) (1000)
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do. It looks like you want to concatenate the`Code`,`Article`and`Balance`as a new column, but what would happen when there are many rows for a Code/Article. Could you add some more sample data to clarify your desired output? What column should be in the output?

Comment: completely unclear what you want

Comment: Since you are only showing us one row of data, that has all the fields you want, it isn't clear why you are asking about merging multiple rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

Note : If you want to concatenate `Numeric datatype` data with `varchar data` then first you have to `convert` the `numeric data` into `varchar type` else you may get **conversion failed error**.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Code) + ' (' + Article
       + ') (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Balance) + ')' new_column,
       Article,
       Amount,
       Paid,
       Balance
FROM   <tablename>
```